# how to change the color of last listview adapter index

Tags: android

below is my `ListView` adapter class i want to change color of last position value, suppose my `ListView` shows 6 elements and i want to change the color of 6th element how i will do that??? i want to change only color of last element text

```
public class CustomAlertAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
TextView titlename;
Context ctx=null;
ArrayList<String> listarray=null;
private LayoutInflater mInflater=null;
public CustomAlertAdapter(Activity activty, ArrayList<String> list)
{
    this.ctx=activty;
    mInflater = activty.getLayoutInflater();
    this.listarray=list;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {

    return listarray.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {       
   final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null ) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.alertlistrow, null);

        holder.titlename = (TextView)  
        convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_titllename);






        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }







    String datavalue=listarray.get(position);

    holder.titlename.setText(datavalue);

    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {


    TextView titlename;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change a property of the inflated view based on position in the data structure

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {

// inflate view
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.alertlistrow, null);
...

// modify view
if(position == listArray.size()-1){
 convertView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.some_color_resource_id);
}

...

// return view
return convertView;
```

so long as that is completed before you return the view inside you getView function.

Worth remembering that is called for each element in the list, and the position is supplied to you.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Try this inside **getView(..)**

```
if (position == listarray.size()-1) {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2)
```

Here position is the position of particular item.

So check if position==total items(total number in your case could be size of arraylist)

and change color by

```
convertView.setBackground("Your Color here");
```

Comment: your arralist size is your last position.

Answer (score 0):

you could check the position and change the color accordingly. For instance:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {       
   final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null ) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.alertlistrow, null);
        holder.titlename = (TextView)  
        convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_titllename);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    String datavalue=listarray.get(position);
    holder.titlename.setText(datavalue);
    int color = (position == getCount() - 1) : Color.BLACK : Color.YELLOW;
    holder.titlename.setTextColor(color)
    return convertView;
}
```